# Bin data into ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like below and I want to create 4 columns to compute accuracy distribution

```
Company Error_Rate
A       9
B      10
c      20
GK     17
GK     18
GK     30
GK     35
GK     25
GK     32
GK     40
GK     50
MB     60
MB     70
MB     70
```

And I desire to have a table like this

```
Company Error_Rate  Above 90%   80% - 90%   65% - 80%   Below 65%
A              9    1           0           0           0
B             10    1           0           0           0
c             20    0           1           0           0
GK            17    0           1           0           0
GK            18    0           1           0           0
GK            30    0           0           1           0
GK            35    0           0           1           0
GK            40    0           0           0           1
```

I tried

```
df['Above 90%'] = np.where(df['Error_Rate']<=10,1,0)
df['80% - 90%'] = np.where(df['Error_Rate'] <= 20,(np.where(df['Error_Rate'] > 10, 1, 0)),0)
df['65% - 80%'] = np.where(df['Error_Rate'] <= 35,(np.where(df['Error_Rate'] > 20, 1, 0)),0)
df['Below 65%'] = np.where(df['Error_Rate']>35,1,0)
```

It is not giving me the desired result. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to write 4 `np.where` conditions to compute a column, you're doing it wrong. I think it'd be wise to consider a different approach.

One succinct option involves `pd.cut` + `pd.get_dummies`.

```
bins = [0, 65, 80, 90, 100]
labels = ['Below 65%', '65% - 80%', '80% - 90%', 'Above 90%']

pd.concat([
    df, pd.get_dummies(pd.cut(100 - df.Error_Rate, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True))
   ], axis=1
)

   Company  Error_Rate  Below 65%  65% - 80%  80% - 90%  Above 90%
0        A           9          0          0          0          1
1        B          10          0          0          0          1
2        c          20          0          0          1          0
3       GK          17          0          0          1          0
4       GK          18          0          0          1          0
5       GK          30          0          1          0          0
6       GK          35          0          1          0          0
7       GK          25          0          1          0          0
8       GK          32          0          1          0          0
9       GK          40          1          0          0          0
10      GK          50          1          0          0          0
11      MB          60          1          0          0          0
12      MB          70          1          0          0          0
13      MB          70          1          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['Above 90%'] = np.where(df['Error_Rate']<=10,1,0)
df['80% - 90%'] = np.where((df['Error_Rate'] <= 20) & (df['Error_Rate'] > 10),1,0)
df['65% - 80%'] = np.where((df['Error_Rate'] <= 35) & (df['Error_Rate'] > 20),1,0)
df['Below 65%'] = np.where(df['Error_Rate']>35,1,0)

print (df)
   Company  Error_Rate  Above 90%  80% - 90%  65% - 80%  Below 65%
0        A           9          1          0          0          0
1        B          10          1          0          0          0
2        c          20          0          1          0          0
3       GK          17          0          1          0          0
4       GK          18          0          1          0          0
5       GK          30          0          0          1          0
6       GK          35          0          0          1          0
7       GK          25          0          0          1          0
8       GK          32          0          0          1          0
9       GK          40          0          0          0          1
10      GK          50          0          0          0          1
11      MB          60          0          0          0          1
12      MB          70          0          0          0          1
13      MB          70          0          0          0          1
```